# jQuery Ajax Remove Specific item from Cart

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, shopping-cart

I have a shopping cart. My cart has remove buttons against each item as follows:

```
....
<tr style="text-size:0.8em">
    <td>Music CD</td><td>23</td><td>£51.89</td>
    <td>
        <form method="post" action="" class="remove">
        <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="1" />
        <input type="image" src="http://.../.../delete.png" name="remove" class="remove" value="x" text="x"/>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-size:0.8em">
    <td>DVD</td><td>5</td><td>£12.23</td>
    <td>
        <form method="post" action="" class="remove">
        <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="2" />
        <input type="image" src="http://.../.../delete.png" name="remove" class="remove" value="x" text="x"/>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
....
```

AND JQuery

```
jQuery('.remove').submit(function(data) {
    // Validate & remove item from cart stuff 
    return false;
});
```

My form works by posting the form, however I wish to ajaxify it.

How do I tell jQuery which pid to remove from the basket?

How do I modify the html & js so that my jQuery script knows which specific product (pid) to remove from the basket?

For the sake of clarity... You will see that there are two forms in this example. If there are more items in the cart, there will be more forms... so how can I tell jQuery which form was submitted when the only difference between the forms is the pid?

Comment: Without seeing the file you are submitting to, it's going to be hard for someone to answer this question thoroughly.  What cart software are you using?  And on which platform?

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I disagree. This has nothing to do with what I am submitting to. All i want to do is somehow tell jQuery which pid to remove from the cart. I can do the rest. Thanks

Comment: My take: handle the event `click` for the "remove" button instead of the `submit` event for the form. Now where do your keep the items?

Comment: @amir I can attach the event to the click event - this is no problem, the product id is stored in <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="2" />. Suppose I do as you say, how do I know what the pid is?

Comment: I'd suggest you modify your remove button and add the pid as its data or attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good to know you solved your problem, Gravy.

Here's some alternative using your previous markup (one posted in your question):

```
$(".remove").click(function(e) {
    pid = $(this).siblings("#name").attr("value");
    // You got the pid. Continue by removing this pid from your cart
});
```

or

```
$(".remove").click(function(e) {
    pid = $(this).siblings("input:hidden").attr("value");
    // You got the pid. Continue by removing this pid from your cart
});
```

That way you don't have to clutter your remove button.

PS:
Sorry for the late reply. I was checking a few reference for the answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the credit, Gravy. Seriously though, I was simply trying to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved thanks to Amir:

```
jQuery('.remove').click(function(data) {
    var pid = jQuery(this).attr('name');
    alert(pid);
    return false;
});
```

HTML change

```
<input type="image" src="http://.../.../delete.png" name="1" class="remove" />
```

I set the pid of the product to the name of the remove button.